# Does storing a MySQL fetch array in a variable only use it once?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a forum system and I use `$users->permissions()` a lot in my thread.php page.  What I want to know is if I do something like `$rights = $users->permissions()` will it only make the call do the database to get the rights of that person one time as opposed to doing something like:

```
if($users->permissions() ==1) { show some mod panel }
elseif($users->permissions == 2) { show some admin panel }


SELECT  `users`.`rights` FROM `users` LEFT JOIN `sessions` ON `sessions`.`user_id` =   `users`.`id` WHERE `sessions`.`session_hash` ='".$this->con->real_escape_string($_COOKIE['session_hash'])."'
```

Comment: We can't say anything if you don't show us the code of `permissions()`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. If you store the result of the call `$users->permissions()` into a variable (e.g. `$rights`) and then use that to check then it will only perform the call to the database once (and speed up the script as it's checking local data at that point rather than firing off a request to a server elsewhere).

However, if you use the code that you have shown in your initial question then it will perform a call to the database each time you check the value.

Personally, I would use a `switch` structure:

```
$rights=$users->permissions();
switch ($rights)
{
  case 1:
    //Show some form
    break;
  case 2:
    //Show something else
    break;
  default:
    //Do something just in case it's not 1 or 2
    break;
}
```

If you want to stick with `if...else` statements, still store the result of `$users->permissions()` into a variable and then wherever you say `$users->permissions()` in the `if` structure, replace it with `$rights`

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing functions and variables.

Unlike functions that runs every time they called, Variables do not run anything. they only contain some value. This is like putting money in the pocket. Once you got your change from a shopkeeper and put it in the pocket, the money stays there in the pocket, require no shopkeeper every time you put your hand in the pocket.

Comment: I am talking about storing the result of a function which gets data from mysql into a variable.  If I use this variable will it only be giving the data stored in the variable or every time I use the variable, will it have to make the call to mysql since the variable is set to the function?